# Tensorflow - Python : How can I use my own data with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new with TensorFow, but i have to use it, so i have a question.

I have to use specific data in a csv file which looks like :

0.5,1,0,0,Slow_Start

1,2,0,0,Slow_Start

1.5,4,0,0,Slow_Start

2,8,0,0,Slow_Start

(Slow_Start is one of the label i have to use).

I successfully import my data using the following code

```
directory = "/home/matthieu/Documents/python/*.csv"
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
tf.train.match_filenames_once(directory),
shuffle=False)
line_reader = tf.TextLineReader()

_, csv_row = line_reader.read(filename_queue)
record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [""]]
time, cwnd, rtt, dupack, Algo = \
tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.pack([
    time,
    cwnd,
    rtt,
    dupack])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # we grab an example from the CSV file.
    for iteration in range(1, 50):

        example, label = sess.run([features, Algo])
        print(example, label)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

But i don't have any ideas on how my datas are stored and how to use it to produce a multiclass classification with the differents labels, knowing that my data represent the size of a window compared to time, so it don't have to be shuffled.

I don't know if i'm clear, but any help would be very nice, thank you !